# Transalting to differens languages

Tags: php

I'am translating website to different languages, and I stopped next to this function, because i can't replace "Skaiciavimas jau vykdomas" with `$AppUI->_('Calculating..')` I get fatal error with non-object. How can i possibly fix it?

```
public function BeginCalc()
{
    if($this->getActive())
    {
        echo "Skaiciavimas jau vykdomas";
    }
    else
    {
        $this->_BeginCalculation();
        echo "Skaiciavimas pradetas";
    }
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you ask. There is no `$AppUI->_('Calculating..')` in your code... If you are talking about replacing that first echo line, then where should `$AppUI` come from? It probably is undefined at that location. You might want to pass that object (if it exists in the calling scope) as parameter to the function. But we cannot tell without you posting more code.

Comment: I want somehow to replace "Skaiciavimas jau vykdomas" with $AppUI->_('Calculating..')And im asking is it possible if not i delete this topic>

Comment: I answered to that in my comment above. Anything you do not understand in that comment? Then ask!

Comment: Its all code, i need to replace with this `$AppUI->_('Calculating..')` becauese i will can translate that Calculating... in other languages. Do you understand? That system only recognize words if they are wrote in this way

Comment: Yes I do understand. But still the same is true what I wrote above: `$AppUI` is not defined in that function. Where should it come from? This is a basic thing in programming: the scope of a variable. I also wrote the solution above: hand over `$AppUI` as argument to the function.

Comment: I tried to explain once more in the answer below.

Comment: @TorresAlGrande your question is a crystal ball issue to us. You're asking us something that may very well be possible but you're not even closely providing enough information for us to determine if and how. Without knowing where `$AppUI` is defined and stored we have nothing to work on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the comments the issue here is that inside the function `BeginCalc()` there simply is not variable `$AppUI`. Where should it come from? Fall from the sky? Appear by magic? Either you have to create it or you have to hand it over as an argument to the function like that:

```
<?php
public function BeginCalc($AppUI)
{
    if($this->getActive())
    {
        $AppUI->_('Calculating..');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->_BeginCalculation();
        echo "Skaiciavimas pradetas";
    }
}
```

Now you can call the function like that:

```
BeginCalc($AppUI);
```

There is not more we can say, since you do not know what `$AppUI` is meant to be and where it should come from...

Comment: As the question is highly unclear (`$AppUI` may be a global, making `global $AppUI` a better solution, or it may be a member of another class, or... or...) I'd recommend removing the answer as it does not conclusively attempt to answer the question.

Comment: Ghe ok, apparently you guessed right, never mind me then.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Using `global $AppUI` _never_ is a good solution! It may work, but it is a _bad_ solution.

Comment: If `$AppUI` is a global variable and intended to be used globally it is the *correct* solution. You cannot know from the amount of code shown whether it's *bad* - it may very well be but it would be the consequence of higher level choices in the surrounding framework or application. Just blindly calling `global` evil is as wrong as blindly calling `goto` or `eval` evil as oft happens - all those constructs have their reasons for existence, and good uses, they're just often abused. But that doesn't invalidate their careful use in specific situations.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes I see your point, but I still disagree. `global` exists out of historical reasons. It introduces a lot of potential dangers. Using something like that simply is not good. Because at the time of the implementation you cannot foresee the failures you create by that. So your code is non-reusable by design. I would call that a _bad solution_. But I _do_ agree that there might be no _right or wrong_ solution here. Maybe that helps :-)